# #1054 - Unknown column 'cla.customer_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    clv.*, cla.customer_id, cla.mobile_no, o.name
FROM
    closed_loyalty_voucher clv
        JOIN
    closed_loyalty_redemption_details clrd ON (clv.issued_to = clrd.customer_id
        AND clrd.voucher_number = clv.voucher_number)
        JOIN
    closed_loyalty_setup_master clsm ON (clsm.id = clrd.setup_id)
        JOIN
    closed_loyalty_accounts cla ON (cla.program_id = clsm.id
        AND cla.created_by = clrd.customer_id)
        JOIN
    outlets o ON (clrd.outlet = o.id)
WHERE
    clv.status = 'Redeemed'
        AND (company LIKE '%%' OR mobile_no LIKE '%%'
        OR name LIKE '%%'
        OR cla.customer_id LIKE '%%')
GROUP BY clv.id
ORDER BY clv.redeemed_date DESC
```

this is my query gets error message #1054 - Unknown column 'cla.customer_id' in 'where clause' please help??

Comment: please share table structure of closed_loyalty_accounts

Comment: CREATE TABLE `closed_loyalty_accounts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `program_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK closed_loyalty_setup_master',
  `customer_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK customers',
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

You have placed a backtick (or quoted identifier) around the entire table dot column name. If you use backticks, you put them around the table, then dot, then around the fieldname.

Backticks aren't necessary though in this case because you are using an underscore in the column name. So change it to `OR cls.customer_id LIKE '%%'`.

The only time quoted identifiers are required is when the column name or table name use a keyword or contain a space. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries.